# Launch Main Activity with Implicit Intent in Service

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an implicit intent in a service that sends information to my main activity, as well as to another class.  I also now want that intent to launch my main activity.  I've looked at the myriad posts related to this, and tried lots of different things--`addCategory`, `setAction(MAIN; the activity's name; you name it, I've tried it...)`, `category.DEFAULT` in the manifest, and several other things that either resulted in ActivityNotFoundExceptions (most commonly) or behavior that was otherwise undesirable.

Here's where the intent is set up and the relevant part of the manifest.  The receiver for the intent is registered in the main activity.

```
final String NEW_DOSES = "changed to protect the innocent";
Intent bluetoothBroadcast = new Intent();
several putExtra lines here
bluetoothBroadcast.setAction(NEW_DOSES);
sendBroadcast(bluetoothBroadcast);

<activity
   android:name=".AsthmaAppActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name" >
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Is it possible to get this intent to launch my main activity with relatively minor changes?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not good practice to start an `Activity` from a `Service` unless it's also as a direct action made by the user. A `Service` is a background component whereas an `Activity` is a UI component - forcing a UI to appear when a user isn't expecting it isn't good for user-experience.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that's a good point, and I meant to mention it in my question.  Though I know that it's generally not good practice to do it, we nevertheless want the app to "be in the user's face" this way.

Comment: Can you describe what the `Intent` extras are for and how often they would change? It's possible you might be able to use a combination of broadcast `Intent` for when the `Activity` is already open and a `STICKY` `Intent` which would be available when the `Activity` is force started from the `Service`.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up.  The extras are a couple of boolean values.  They can flip from one sending of the intent to the next, of course (that's why they're being sent).  It seems to me that I have been able to change variable values in an activity from other classes (though I can't find any examples in my code now), so I suppose that if the extras are a problem, rather than sending them with the intent I could just create some booleans in the activity and change them from the service as needed.  If you can provide any more information about what you're suggesting, that would be great.

Comment: A normal broadcast sent using `sendBroadcast(...)` is a 'one-shot' event which only works for currently registered receivers. This is why the method Christos describes doesn't work if your `Activity` isn't currently running. As I suspect you realise, at that point the receiver isn't registered until after the 'one-shot' event has passed. Using `sendStickyBroadcast(...)`, the `Intent` 'sticks' and can be retrieved as the return value of `registerReceiver(...)` this means even if the receiver wasn't registered at the time the sticky `Intent` was broadcast, it can get it later when registered.

Comment: See the docs for `sendStickyBroadcast(...)` in the `ContextWrapper` class here...http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#sendStickyBroadcast(android.content.Intent)

Comment: It doesn't seem that `sendStickyBroadcast` will help in the launching of the activity, though, or am I missing something?  I can't use both `sendStickyBroadcast` and `startActivity` with the same Intent, can I?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but no with sendBroadcast(bluetoothBroadcast); sendBroadcast does not launch an activity. You must use startActivity to achieve this. For example here is what a launcher application will do in order to launch an application:

```
public static void LaunchApplication(Context cx, String packagename) {
    PackageManager pm = cx.getPackageManager();
    Intent i = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(ai.packageName);
    if (i != null) cx.startActivity(i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
}
```

You can easily adjust the extras and the data needed in order to launch the activity. For example if your activity is named myActivity then you can go like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(cx, myActivity.class);
//Put the extras and the data you want here...
//If you are launching the activity from a receiver component you must use
//i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
cx.startActivity(i);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I did try what you suggested above, but because of the way the receiver is used in the activity, the activity no longer performed the desired actions.  I could certainly change the code in the activity to do what I need when startActivity  calls it, but I was hoping not to have to do that. I don't now remember, but I think that using startActivity also meant that the intent wasn't being received by the other class that has a receiver for it.

Comment: If your main activity has to be the receiver for some actions and also the main entry point for your application then you must code it like this. What I mean is that you can not launch your main activity if it does not perform the desired actions. Maybe you should consider to use different components for your receiver and the main Activity.
Bottom line is that I cannot think a "right" way to start an activity via sendBroadcast with the same Intent broadcasted to a receiver inside the activity (If I get this right)...

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean when you say, "you can not launch your main activity if it does not perform the desired actions", but it seems that I'm going to have to use startActivity to launch my activity.  I guess I'll have to use sendBroadcast for the other class that needs to receive the intent, and startActivity to launch the main activity.  I assume I don't need two separate Intents, though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In your first comment you say "... the activity no longer performed the desired actions..." so I assumed that your activity is not following the android guidelines and lifecycle restrictions. That may be ok but not for the main activity of an application. That's why I am proposing to use a different component.